# Function Closure Dart Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So , I have this in my code . A screen widget getting 4 parameters from another screen.

```
    class succesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  String salaire, valeurAcq, valeurApport, moisRembours;

  //Constructeur du screen successPage
  succesPage(
      this.salaire, this.valeurApport, this.valeurAcq, this.moisRembours);

  double calculCredit(salaire, valeurAcq, valeurApport, moisRembours) 
  {
    double res = (double.parse(salaire.text) -
        double.parse(valeurApport.text) / double.parse(moisRembours.text));
    return res;
  }
```

I'm using that`calculCredit` function with the 4 variables .

The problem is that I'm getting this error on my emulator :

```
Closure:(dynamic,dynamic,dynamic,dynamic) => double from Function 'calculCredit(salaire,valeurAcq,ValeurApport,moisRembours)
```

The use of the function

```
Text(
                  "Le montant à rembourser DT/Mois : $calculCredit(salaire,valeurAcq,valeurApport,moisRembours) ",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                  ),
                )
```

Comment: It makes helping you easier if you 1. Follow the naming conventions (classes are named like this: SuccessPage) and 2. You use English for naming your classes, variables and functions.

Comment: Try using the string interpolation like this: "This is a text: ${for.moreComplex.values}

Comment: getting this error now on salaire variable : NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'text'. Receiver: "90000" Tried calling: text)

Comment: Also as a side note, I´d prefer storing the result in a property of SuccessPage and refer to it in your string interpolation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method like this:

```
  double calculCredit(salaire, valeurAcq, valeurApport, moisRembours) 
  {
    double res = (double.parse(salaire) -
        double.parse(valeurApport) / double.parse(moisRembours));
    return res;
  }
```

Then Do like this :

```
 Text(
         "Le montant à rembourser DT/Mois : ${calculCredit(salaire,valeurAcq,valeurApport,moisRembours).toString()} ",
         textAlign: TextAlign.center,
         style: TextStyle(
           fontSize: 15,
           color: Colors.grey[700],
         ),
  )
```

Comment: Getting this error now , NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'text'.
Receiver: "90000"
Tried calling: text)

Comment: I edited my answer, hope to work